# PHP regular expression for directory

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression that would take the string after the last forward slash.

For example, considering I have the following string:

```
C:/dir/file.txt
```

I need to take only the **file.txt** part (string).

Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a regex.

```
$string = "C:/dir/file.txt";

$filetemp = explode("/",$string);

$file = end($filetemp);
```

Edited because I remember the latest PHP spitting errors out about chaining these types of functions.

Answer (score 3):

If your strings are always paths you should consider the [`basename()`](http://php.net/basename) function.

Example:

```
$string = 'C:/dir/file.txt';

$file = basename($string);
```

Otherwise, the other answers are great!

Answer (score 1):

The `strrpos()` function finds the last occurrence of a string. You can use it to figure out where the file name starts.

```
$path = 'C:/dir/file.txt';
$pos  = strrpos($path, '/');
$file = substr($path, $pos + 1);
echo $file;
```